# Boggle program not finding all possible words

Tags: java, recursion, hashset

I'm writing a program that will read an input file containing a 5x5  grid such as the one below and pulls all the possible words it can create from a dictionary file.

The code compiles fine but seems to miss out on some of the words. I attached a screenshot of the outputting I'm getting.

Grid:

[image: Grid]

Console Output:

[image: Console Output]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isWord(String word)
{
    return word.length() >=3 && dict.contains(word);
}

public static List<String> foundWords = new ArrayList<>();

public static void findWordsUtil(String board[][], boolean visited[][], int i, int j, String str)
{
    visited[i][j] = true;

    if (str.length() == 15)
    {
        return;
    }

    str = str + board[i][j];

    if (isWord(str))
    {
        if (!foundWords.contains(str))
            {
                foundWords.add(str);
            }


    }


    for (int row = i-1; row<=i+1 && row<board.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col=j-1; col<=j+1 && col<board[0].length; col++)
        {
            if (row>=0 && col>=0 && !visited[row][col])
                {
                    findWordsUtil(board, visited, row, col, str);
                }   
        }
    }

    if (str != null && str.length() > 0)
    {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
    }

    visited [i][j] = false;
}


public static void findWords(String board[][])
{
    boolean visited[][] = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];

    String str = "";

    for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<board[0].length; j++)
        {
            findWordsUtil(board, visited, i, j, str);
        }
    }
```

I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction with this. From what I can tell, the class is reading through the whole grid, so I'm confused why I'm only returning half the words.

Comment: One probably mistake I see is that if str.length is 15, you set visited[i][j] to true, but never set it to false.  A dubious design aspect I see, which you might not be able to do anything about, is that you'll enumerate all 15 character strings without regard for whether there exists any word that starts with the leftmost portion.  A good search program should use a dictionary-lookup function that reports whether the a sequence of letters is a valid word, the start of a longer word, both, or neither, and not bother recursing if the current string of letters isn't the start of a valid word.